# let $A$ be a set of continuous functions over the closed interval $[0,1]$..........

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

let $A$ be a set of continuous  functions over the closed interval $[0,1]$, which applies to the following conditions:

$ 1: \forall f \in A , \forall x \in [0,1] , f(x) \geq 0 $

$2: \forall f, g \in A , f + g \in A $

$3:  \forall x \in [0,1], \textbf{there is}   f \in A  \quad \textbf{so that} f(x) > 0 $

Prove that there is $  h \in A$  so that $ \forall  x \in [0,1], h(x) > 0$.

Answer (score 5):

Hints.

1. Set $U_f=\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)>0\}$.
2. Prove that the family $\{U_f:f\in A\}$ is an open cover of $[0,1]$.
3. Apply the fact that $[0,1]$ is compact.
4. Apply the fact that $A$ is closed under sums.

Comment: How can I prove " $  h \in A$  so that $ \forall  x \in [0,1], h(x) > 0$"?                  
please, give me more guidance Thanks. .

Comment: @joe Take $f_1,\dots,f_n$ such that $U_{f_1},\dots,U_{f_n}$ cover $[0,1]$. Then define $h=f_1+\dots+f_n$.